# user-space application for tmp102 sensor driver

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, i2c

I have a [thermo3 click](http://www.mikroe.com/click/thermo3/) which has [tmp102 sensor](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/tmp102.pdf).

To read data from it, I have written a user-space application using I2C as follows:

```
fd = open("/dev/i2c-0", O_RDWR))
ioctl(fd, I2C_SLAVE, 0x48)
read(fd, &buf, 2)
```

But then I found its driver in [linux source code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.1/drivers/hwmon/tmp102.c).

So I am wondering:

1) Can I write a user-space application which uses this driver's API's (means using driver's device file)?

2) How I2C user-space application works without using this driver (because this driver is not enabled in my kernel when I was using i2c user-space application) or This is the way I2C works?

Answer (score 1):

1) This is an hwmon device, you don't have a device file to use. Instead the api is in `/sys/class/hwmon`. In particular, you want to read the `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmonX/tempX_input` files

2) By using `/dev/i2c-0`, your are directly communicating on the i2c bus, effectively bypassing any kernel driver. You then have to know the details for any device you use (registers to read and their meaning...) instead of using the generic Linux kernel abstraction.

Comment: means reading data from /sys/class/hwmon/hwmonX/tempX_input is the ideal way compared to reading through i2c bus

Comment: I enabled the Device drivers -> Hardware Monitoring support -> tmp102 in my kernel but I couldn't see any file created under /sys/class/hwmon. But there is some file created here /sys/bus/i2c/drivers/tmp102

Comment: Perhaps you didn't enabled everything you need. Don't forget about udev which provides a mechanism to load the driver based on events, though I think it's not always the case (some old, i.e. non-ACPI, non-DT, platforms can load it either from built-in code, or manually).

Comment: The i2c bus is non discoverable, you need to explicitely add the tmp102 to your platform. This is architecture dependent and you didn't provide that information.

Answer (score 1):

User Level Application can not interact with hardware. They can communicate by system call (ioctl, open, read and write etc) and Sysfs(sysfs is a virtual file system).

1 :- Your device is hwmom device. Your Driver is "tmp102". Driver Expose these three **temp1_input**, **temp1_max_hyst** and **temp1_max** sysfs entry for user-level application.

```
 SENSOR_DEVICE_ATTR(temp1_input, S_IRUGO, tmp102_show_temp, NULL , 0);
 SENSOR_DEVICE_ATTR(temp1_max_hyst, S_IWUSR | S_IRUGO, tmp102_show_temp,  tmp102_set_temp, 1);
 SENSOR_DEVICE_ATTR(temp1_max, S_IWUSR | S_IRUGO, tmp102_show_temp,
          tmp102_set_temp, 2);
```

You can read /sys/class/hwmom/tmp102/temp1_input sysfs file.
you can read and write these two sysfs file /sys/class/hwmom/tmp102/temp1_max_hyst and sys/class/hwmom/tmp102/temp1_max.

2 :- The files in /dev are actual devices files which UDEV creates at run time.A device file is an interface for a device driver that appears in a file system as if it were an ordinary file. Your driver has expose some other device file. thermal_zone_of_sensor_register(hwmon_dev, 0,hwmon_dev, &tmp102_of_thermal_ops). You have /dev/hwmom_dev node.

User-Level application can't directly communicate any of i2c-device or hardware. Linux kernel has limitation. Application need driver as interface to controle any of device.